# How to map 3 numbers to a value (Dynamic Programming)

Tags: c++, dictionary, dynamic, key

Using the Dynamic Programming idea, I want to store 3 numbers (x,y,z) which map to a value (v).

For every new value of x,y,z, I want to check whether its value already exists or not. (to avoid re-computation)

The order of x,y,z is not important. That is 1,1,2 and 2,1,1 etc should map to the same value.

x,y,z are calculated using for loops (2 nested loops as x+y+z = n (given))

How should I achieve this? Will it require a custom data structure?

Thanks

Coding in C++

Comment: You can create a value with three members with `struct value {int x, y, z;};`. If you have several of those, a `std::vector<value>` might be used to store them.

Comment: Why is the question downvoted?

Comment: @user7777777 I've created a loop which computes the values x,y,z. Saving and accessing these later is what I couldn't understand

Comment: @BoPersson x,y,z are typically keys which will map to a value. How will I check the order if I create a struct?

Answer (score 0):

Sort these three values first since their relative sequence is not important and then join them with special character as `#` to generate a string.

For example, in your case 1,1,2 and 2,1,1 will be first sorted as the same sequence 1,1,2 and then concatenating them will give us `1#1#2` - a string then the key will be unique to meet your requirement.

If anything else is overlooked, perhaps you should provided more detailed requirements here.

Comment: Nope, that's exactly what I want to do. You suggest mapping this string to a value? It's a nice idea. Will try and update